# Time series : Predicting when a variable will reach a certain value (seasonal sensor data) python

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, sensor-fusion

So I have a seasonal time-series with 2 variable "Time" and "Sensor mesure" and I want to predict the date when that measure would reach a certain value . Can anyone suggest models/Algos that can help (I'm a beginner)
PS : Using python

Comment: Hard to say without knowing way more about the problem. What is the sensor measuring? Do you have any conceptions of a possible underlying generative process behind the data? Maybe check out Poisson point processes and the exponential distribution as a starting point.

Comment: @gowrath Thank you, the sensor mesures the vibration of a rotating equipment in a fixed point (hence the seasonality), it generates a waveform and the measure is calculated using Fourier Transform

Answer (score 0):

For time series data, you can use LSTM or GRU neural networks. They would be the easiest to solve your problem.